# Why my server is not working after reverted from SUPEE-6788

Tags: magento-1.8

I had installed the SUPEE-6788 and tested but it has not worked.So,I reverted my code and tested the server but it not working it is showing page not found when I click on anyone.Please help me.

Comment: Please help me.It is very important for me.

Comment: admin setting in web tab `Search Engines Optimization` set to `no` or add `htacess` file.

Comment: Ya added but my tools module is not working

Comment: add ur old .htacees file in root folder

Comment: Added the file but it is showing same error page

Comment: if you added the `Search Engines Optimization` set to `yes` and then check

Comment: Now it is showing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem is with your search engine optimization.

`Search Engines Optimization` set to `yes` or add `.htacess` file to your root folder.

Comment: Can you please see my new question and give the guidance on that.

Comment: i am  familiar with that question too the answer was provided by me. can you give me model name or database table for selecting the email?

Comment: DB table name:mg_serviceprovider

Comment: is there is single data or multiple data for that?

Comment: it contains a form and checkboxes

Comment: Hey could you please reply.

Comment: every service provider have it own email you want to send it there?

Comment: Yes and it should send only for emails whose "isblooddonor" checkbox is true

Comment: will do that in after an hour need to go now i will write query for you.

Comment: Ok.But,try to solve my issue as i need to submit it today

Comment: answer ur question check it